# Why is document not a reserved word in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I can declare a variable called 'document' and set it to something like "test" however the document.getElementById will still work! How come?

Answer (score 3):

Because reserved words are part of the grammar of language, whereas *document* is a special object created by the browser that can be accessed by JavaScript.

Think of it this way:  If you were using JavaScript to write a command line script, there would be no document object, right?  However there would be things like *for*, *if*, and *function* because these are parts of the language.

Comment: Yes document is just another Object Variable/Name like any other.

Answer (score 2):

In browser contexts, the [globally scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) `window` has a *readonly* property [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/document).

When you write `document`, you really are referencing `window.document`.

So writing `document = "test"` is equivalent to writing `window.document = "test"`.

Setting a *readonly* property [will throw a `TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Read-only) in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), and **will silently fail when in non-strict mode**. This is most likely what you are seeing.

```js
'use strict';

// This line will throw an error in strict mode: `TypeError: setting getter-only property "document"`
document = "test";
```

Additionally, if you were to write something like `var document = "test"`, [you aren't actually re-declaring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) `document` since it already exists in the global scope. If instead you were to write `let document = "test"` or `const document = "test"`, then you'd get a [`SyntaxError`: redeclaration of non-configurable global property document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Redeclared_parameter).

```js
let document = "test";
```